# VSCode extension API - text selection

Tags: javascript, selection, vscode-extensions

I am having trouble updating the vs code selection after the extension triggers.

```js
const selection = editor.selection;
const text = editor.document.getText(selection);
const modText = "/* " + text + " */";
 
let edit = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();
let startPos = new vscode.Position(selection.start.line, selection.start.character);
let endPos = new vscode.Position(selection.start.line + text.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length - 1, selection.start.character + text.length);
let range = new vscode.Range(startPos, endPos);
edit.replace(editor.document.uri, range, modText);
return vscode.workspace.applyEdit(edit);
```

I am selecting everything below.

```
 body {
    background: blue;
  }
```

The result after trigger is:

```
/* body {
    background: blue;
  } */
```

but the selection is missing the initial /*

How do I change the selection to include the initial
/* ???

Comment: If you are trying to do a toggle block comment on a selection, VSCode has a shortcut built in: `Shift` + `Alt` + `A`. Open your Keyboard Shortcuts in VSCode with `Ctrl + K` `Ctrl + S` and in the search type `"shift+alt+a"` and you'll see it

Comment: I don't understand, there is a leading `/*`.  What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks. To be clear, this is not for vscode native code commenting. I am updating an extension which does custom commenting, and my question pertains to using the vscode API.

Correct, there is the initial /* as expected, but the selection range does not include the initial /* as I would like.

Comment: You want to select the entire comment from and including `/*` to and including the `*/`?  Your result doesn't show **any** selection?  [Also, you should add `@Mark` to your comments so that SO notifies me of them.]

Comment: @Mark Correct, including /* ... */ . I did give it my best attempt to change the selection but could not get it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to the end of your code:

```js
await vscode.workspace.applyEdit(edit);     // add the next line
editor.selections = [new vscode.Selection(startPos, new vscode.Position(endPos.line, endPos.character+6))];
```

See that it adds 6 characters to account for the `/*`  and  `*/` to a `Selection` that should include your entire comment characters and included text.

This code does the same thing and is a little more compact:

```js
editor.selections = [new vscode.Selection(startPos, endPos.translate(0, 6))];
```

By the way, your code can be simplified to:

```js
    const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
    const selection = editor.selection;
    const text = editor.document.getText(selection);
    const modText = "/* " + text + " */";
     
    let edit = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();
    edit.replace(editor.document.uri, selection, modText);
    vscode.workspace.applyEdit(edit);

    return editor.selections = [new vscode.Selection(selection.start, selection.end.translate(0, 6))];
```

With the result you want.

---

Better is to use an `editBuilder` as it handles preserving selections across edits much better than `WorkspaceEdit` does.  That is why in the original answer you have to manually manipulate the selection after the edit to handle the different length of the new text - 6 characters longer.

But with an `editBuilder` you can simply do this:

```js
    // make sure this is async so you can use await below
let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('myExtensionID.myCommandName', async (args) => {

    const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
    const selection = editor.selection;
    const text = editor.document.getText(selection);
    const modText = "/* " + text + " */";
     
    await editor.edit(editBuilder => {
        editBuilder.replace(selection, modText);
    });

    return;
}
```

In a simple scenario, you should be able to use the `editBuilder`, but in some more complicated cases it can be difficult to use the `editBuilder` approach and then you can use `WorkspaceEdit`.

Comment: I think it should be `endPos.character+3`, not `6`.

Comment: @Philippe I added some info to the answer.  Since the question was using `WorkspaceEdit` replacing a selection does not nicely result in a matching selection of the new text as the OP wanted - so it had to be manually done.  If  you test it you will see that `6` is required, not `3`.

Comment: I tried to select `body {...background:` then run the command. The final selection was not right.

Comment: @Philippe Are you selecting the entire selector?  We would also have to see your js code since it is working for me and the OP.

Comment: I copy/pasted your code under the line `By the way, your code can be simplified to:`, adding an `await` in front of `vscode.workspace.applyEdit(edit);`. I selected multiple of lines, but on the last line, only extended to half of the line.